# Alterar ícone da barra de títulos e da janela

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Quero alterar o ícone da barra de títulos da janela do Java, conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou indo no método `initComponents()` e deixando como está no código abaixo, mas a linha `setIconImage(iconeTitulo);` fica como erro.

```
public FrmConfiguracoes() {
        initComponents();

    URL caminhoImagem = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("smile.png");
    Image    iconeTitulo = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(caminhoImagem);
    setIconImage(iconeTitulo);

    }
```

Não reconhece o comando e não altera o ícone. O que posso fazer? E como alterar o logo que fica no ícone minimizado, conforma imagem abaixo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na hora de pegar a URL da imagem, remova a chamada `getClassLoader()` da forma que segue:

```
public FrmConfiguracoes() {

    initComponents();

    URL caminhoImagem = this.getClass().getResource("smile.png");
    Image    iconeTitulo = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(caminhoImagem);
    setIconImage(iconeTitulo);
}
```

Tenha em mente que mesmo assim só irá funcionar se a classe e a imagem estiverem no mesmo diretório(pacote) do projeto.

---

Outra forma é fazer a chamada utilizando a classe [**`ImageIO`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html):

```
public FrmConfiguracoes() {

    initComponents();

    try {

        Image iconeTitulo = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("smile.png"));

    } catch(IOException ex) {
      System.out.println("Erro ao importar icone: " ex.getMessage());
    }         
    setIconImage(iconeTitulo);
}
```

Ambas as formas já alteram o ícone da janela e também o ícone que é exibido na barra de tarefas do windows, exibindo a imagem que você apontou no seu projeto, veja um exemplo na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Esta dando erro. Usei o código abaixo:  //alterando logotipo
        URL caminhoImagem = this.getClass().getResource("/logo.bmp");
        Image    iconeTitulo = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(caminhoImagem);
        setIconImage(iconeTitulo); Ao executar o programa é dado o erro: Uncaught error fetching image:
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Se não me engano tem que ser png ou jpg o formato, e essa barra ai é desnecessária se a imagem está no mesmo pacote que a classe.

Comment: @RodrigoStortideOliveira o código acima resolveu o problema?

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Testei com JPG sem a barra mas não deu certo

Comment: @RodrigoStortideOliveira então o problema é com o caminho. Se estiver usando netbeans, arraste a foto pro mesmo pacote da sua classe da tela,  e passe apenas o nome.extensao.